# Determining wether a set of complex numbers is open or closed

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $S = \{z: arg(z)= \pi/4\}$. Is S open? Is it closed? What?'s its boundary?

I graph it in polar and it just seems to be a line from the origin with $\theta = \pi/4$. What is a better way to picture this set?

Comment: No better way, a ray is what it is. To answer your question, think about this: does it contain a neighborhood of all of its elements? Does it contain all of its limit points?

Comment: Be sure to consider 0.